# binary data to image raw python

Tags: python, image, networking, binary

so here is what I'm trying to do:
There is this image server that will send data on port 5003
The format of the data it will transmit is as follows
1 byte for the image type(0=raw, 1=JPEG)
then the next 4 byte for the image size
then after that there will be n byte with the following order
2 byte for width, 2 byte for height, 1 byte for B, 1 byte for R, 1 byte for G

So what I'm trying to do is to get the data and transform it into an image with the following code:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
import socket
import sys
import binascii
from PIL import Image
from StringIO import StringIO


# Connect to the server image
serverHost = 'localhost'
serverPort = 5003
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((serverHost, serverPort))

print >>sys.stderr, 'Connecting to host: ' +  str(serverHost) 
print >>sys.stderr, 'and server Port: ' + str(serverPort)

s.settimeout(1)

#Receive the image type
imageType = s.recv(1)
print>>sys.stderr, 'received %r' %binascii.hexlify(imageType)
print>>sys.stderr, 'Unpacked: ', int(binascii.hexlify(imageType), 16)
received = imageType.__len__()
print>> sys.stderr, "Received: ", received 

#Receive the image size
imageSize = s.recv(4)
print>>sys.stderr, 'received %r' %binascii.hexlify(imageSize)
print>>sys.stderr, 'Unpacked: ', int(binascii.hexlify(imageSize), 16)
received = imageSize.__len__()
print>> sys.stderr, "Received: ", received 


#Receive the image Data
imageData = ''
received =0
while(received < int(binascii.hexlify(imageSize), 16)):
  buffer = s.recv(4096)
  imageData += buffer
  received += buffer.__len__()
  print>> sys.stderr, "Received: ", received 

img = Image.fromstring('RGB', (1280, 720), imageData, 'raw')

#img = Image.open(StringIO(binascii.hexlify(imageData)))
img = img.convert('RGB')
img.save('out.png')

#file = open('test.png', 'w');
#file.write(imageData)
#file.close()

#When we receive the image, we send the acknowledgement
s.send('OK')
s.close()`enter code here`
```

But everytime I run the code it always get this kind of error

```
"Value error not enough Image Data"
```

And if change

```
img = Image.fromstring('RGB', (1280, 720), imageData, 'raw')
```

to

```
img = Image.fromstring('BRG', (1280, 720), imageData, 'raw')
```

I get this error:

```
Value error: Unrecognized mode,
```

Anyone knows how to solve this kind of problem?

Comment: The second error is simple due to PIL not supporting 'BRG' for creating a image from a string. The first error is simply due to you not having enough image data to build an image of 1280 * 720. Check that len(imageData) == width * height * numchannels. Also, why aren't you using `struct` ? Besides all this, the other possible source of error is the server, which was not presented by you. As a suggestion, you will also need to send the image mode, otherwise how are you going to know whether you have a 'L', 'RGB', and others, as the mode in your original jpg ?

Comment: in addition to what @mmgp said (+1 on `struct` module) you might need to call s.recv() multiple times i.e., `s.recv(4)` may return less than 4 bytes (you could call `f = s.makefile('rb'); f.read(4)` to make sure either 4 bytes are read or EOF is encountered. Use `len(buff)` instead of `buff.__len__()`

Comment: You mentioned "2 bytes for width, 2 bytes for height", but I don't see it being recv()ed?

Comment: mmgp: yeah, after I resize the image from 1280x720 to 320x240, the error is no longer there. Actually this is my first time using Python, so can you explain on how to use **struct** , For the server itself, it is from **USARSim Image Server**. And it provides the information about what image will it send and the type of it
J.F. Sebastian, I cause I could try that, btw what's the difference between **len(buff)** and **buff.__len__()**?
ArminRigo For that part, I just copy a code from the Internet
And another reason is I don't how to construct the image from the information above,

Answer (score 2):

It is better to debug these problems when both the code for server as well the client are fully given (but simplified to just show the problem).

So, following is a very basic client based on your initial code and description. Note that `image_type` isn't used, it is just there because you mentioned you wanted to differentiate between JPEG and RAW. I always assume the received data is RGB data, you can adapt this to your actual problem. The main difference here is the use of `struct`, which is a standard way to pack data in a common format to send over network and avoid problems related to byte ordering. This code also expects to receive the image width and height (which was not present in your code), so you can reconstruct the image in the client.

```
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image

def recv(sock, size):
    data = ''
    to_receive = size
    while to_receive > 0:
        data += sock.recv(size)
        to_receive = size - len(data)
    return data

serv_host = ''
serv_port = 5003

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect((serv_host, serv_port))

s.settimeout(1)

image_type = struct.unpack('!b', recv(s, 1))[0]
print "Image type: %d" % image_type
image_size = struct.unpack('!i', recv(s, 4))[0]
print "Image size: %d" % image_size
image_width, image_height = struct.unpack('!hh', recv(s, 4))
print "Image dimensions: %d x %d" % (image_width, image_height)

# Receive image data
image_data = recv(s, image_size)
print len(image_data)

# When we receive the image, we send the acknowledgement.
s.send('OK')
s.close()

img = Image.fromstring('RGB', (image_width, image_height), image_data)
img.save('out.png')
```

Since the server was not included, following is a simple one that respects the protocol you described. I did not bother checking for fully received data in the server. Also note that this server only serves a single image that is specified in the command line when you run it. Again, adapt for your problem. Also observe that I'm not sending the image mode, which may be a problem in the actual application.

```
import sys
import socket
import struct
from PIL import Image

host = ''
port = 5003
backlog = 5

serv_img = Image.open(sys.argv[1])
simg_size = serv_img.size
serv_data = serv_img.tostring()
data_size = len(serv_data)

print "Serving data of size %d" % data_size

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
s.bind((host, port))
s.listen(backlog)
while True:
    client, address = s.accept()

    client.sendall(struct.pack('!b', 1))
    client.sendall(struct.pack('!i', data_size))
    client.sendall(struct.pack('!hh', *simg_size))
    client.sendall(serv_data)

    data = client.recv(2)
    if data == 'OK':
        print "OK", address

    client.close()
```

The raised note about not using `__len__` is simply due to it being a special method in Python, which is called by `len` itself. If you don't have any good reason to use special methods, then don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned using the image server from USARSim. Here's the code I'm using to receive images from USARSim (UT2004 version):

```
def get_image(sock):    
    image_type = struct.unpack('b', sock.recv(1))[0]    
    image_size = struct.unpack('>i', sock.recv(4))[0]

    if image_size < 250000:      
        image_data = ""
        received = 0
        while (received < image_size):
            data = sock.recv(image_size-received)
            received += len(data)
            image_data += data        

        filename = "image_%s.jpg" % str(now())
        with open(filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(image_data)

def write_ack(sock):
    sock.send("OK")

def main():
   sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   sock.connect((host, port))

   while True:
       get_image(sock)
       write_ack(sock)
```